# Magento admin showing blank page after upgrade

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, upgrade

I have upgraded Magento from 1.7.x to 1.9.2.4 using Magento connect.

Now when I open admin panel it's showing blank page, but the frontend is working fine.

I have cleared cache and session but it's still showing blank page.

Comment: set display_errors on in php.ini

Comment: Have you tried a page refresh? I always get a blank page when I log in to admin yet a page refresh displays the dashboard normally!

Answer (score 0):

You need to debug the system as:

1. You can enable printing errors by renaming file `local.xml.sample to local.xml`. file location `magentoRootDirectory/errors/`
2. set permissions 777 to `magentoRootDirectory/var` folder
3. In Index page change the following:

   error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

to

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Set `$_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true`

and uncomment this line

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```